# when using svg in react its gives me error everytime

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, svg

I created an SVG using adobe illustrator But when trying to add to the project it just gives an error and the same goes with SVG I created with SVGator in short every single SVG gives me an error but using in bare HTML project its runs perfectly.

can anyone guide me on how to use SVG to react

errors I got

1. SVG with Adobe

   ```
   <style>.cls-1{fill:url(#a);}</style>
   ```

after adding {} as it suggested gives me this

```
Private names are only allowed in property accesses (`obj.#a`) or in `in` expressions 
 <style>.cls-1{{fill:url(#a)}}</style>
```

2. Error when SVG is downloaded from the website

   Compiled with problems:

   ```
    ERROR

    [eslint]
    src\components\common\RegisterSvg.js
      Line 8:32256:  Parsing error: Unexpected token (8:32256)
   ```

Comment: Consider using template string children as a work-around? `<style>{\`.cls-1{fill:url(#a);}\`}</style>`

Answer (score 0):

For those who might get this error with their SVG try importing SVG and use it as an image if SVG is static

```
import FormSvg from "./svg/newtest.svg
<img src={FormSvg} alt="svg"/>
```

if SVG has animation attached to it then add the SVG JavaScript in the useEffect and then use it as a normal SVG

```
useEffect(() => {
  // ... javascript goes here 
  // !function ... long code (<script>code from script</script>)
  }, []);
  return (
      // SVG part goes here
      <Svg/>
  )
```